# Where to Input the function I want to run in Bootstrap JS

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I want to use the below JS in my web app to not allow the information to process unless all fields have information in them. Where or how do I insert the function to run if all fields are full?

```
// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function () {
'use strict'

  // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
  var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')

  // Loop over them and prevent submission
  Array.prototype.slice.call(forms)
    .forEach(function (form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        if (!form.checkValidity()) {
          event.preventDefault()
          event.stopPropagation()
        }

        form.classList.add('was-validated')
      }, false)
    })
})()
```

Comment: Just add `required` to the form fields and make sure the selects have a first option with empty value. The code you posted is useless as far as I can see

Answer (score 0):

since **if** check if its not valid then you can add **else** if you want you do something if its valid.

```
if (!form.checkValidity()) {
  event.preventDefault() 
  event.stopPropagation()
 } else {
   // code here
 }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 